# Intermediate value theorem (IVT) for a function

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity

My teacher said that the function defined by: 
\begin{equation}
  f(x)=\begin{cases}
    \dfrac{1}{x}, & \text{if $x \neq 0$}.\\
    0, & \text{if $x = 0$}.
  \end{cases}
\end{equation}
is a discontinuous function that satisfies the intermediate value theorem, but I'm not sure about this last property.

Let's check the IV theorem:

Let $f(x)$ be a function that is continuous on $[a,b]$. If $k$ is a number between $f(a)$ and $f(b)$, then there exists (at least) one $c$, with $a<c<b$, such that $f(c)=k$.

Take for instance the interval $[-1,1]$ as $[f(a),f(b)]$. If $k$ is taken as $1/2$ we find out that $c$ is equal to $2$, a number that doesn't belong to the interval $[a,b] = [-1,1]$. So, the function doesn't satisfy the IVT. Am I right?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: You are right. Go tell your teacher tomorrow.

Comment: @GuyFsone The intermediate value theorem is quite different from the mean value theorem. Please don't tag questions exclusively about the former with [tag:mean-value-theorem]. Whether that tag should exist at all is questionable anyway.

Comment: @DanielFischer I totally agree with you. it was a misleading